# Local BLAST NCBI C++ Exception

Tags: bioinformatics, blast, ncbi

I'm getting an error trying to to use blast v2.12 against a local nt database. I've downloaded nt twice from the ftp server thinking the first time it was corrupt but that didn't change anything.

My command is:

```
blastn -db nt -num_threads 8 -outfmt "6 qseqid sacc stitle ssciname nident qlen" -num_alignments 10000 -query QUERY > OUT.csv
```

The error is:

```
Error: NCBI C++ Exception:
    T0 "/build/ncbi-blast+-S1iyIZ/ncbi-blast+-2.9.0/c++/src/serial/objistrasnb.cpp", line 499: Error: byte 90: overflow error ( at [].[].gi)
    T0 "/build/ncbi-blast+-S1iyIZ/ncbi-blast+-2.9.0/c++/src/serial/member.cpp", line 769: Error: ncbi::CMemberInfoFunctions::ReadWithSetFlagMember() - error while reading seqid ( at Blast-def-line-set.[].[].seqid.[].[].gi)
```

I've tried multiple queries. The following actually works:

```
TGTTCACACCTCACTTCTTAACTATTATATCATTATTTTGACAAACAGACTACAAATGTAATATTATTGGATTACATTTGTAGTACAAAAGGAGGAAGAGATGAAAAAAATTTATATTAGTGTGCTAGTTCTTTTACTAATTATGATTATAATAACTTGGTTATTCAAAGATGACGATATTGAGAAAACAATTAGTTCTATTGAAAAAGGAAACTATAACGAAGTATATAAAAATAGTTCAGAAAAATCTAAACTGGCATATGGAGAAGAAGAAATTGTAGATAGGAATAAAAAAATTTACAAAGATTTAAGTGTCAATAACTTAAAAATTACTAATCATGAAATTAAAAAAACTGGAAAAGATAAAAAGCAAGTTGATGTTAAATATAACATATATACAAAATATGGAACTATACGACGTAATACACAATTAAACTTTATTTATGAAGATAAGCATTGGAAATTAGATTGGAGACCAGACGTAATAGTACCTGGTTTGAAAAATGGACAGAAAATTAATATAGAAACATTAAAATCAGAGCGAGGCAAAATAAAAGATAGAAATGGTATAGAATTAGCTAAAACTGGAAATACATATGAAATCGGTATTGTCCCTAACAAAACACCCAAAGAAAAATATGATGATATTGCTCGTGACTTACAAATTGATACAAAAGCTATAACCAATAAAGTTAATCAAAAATGGGTTCAGCCAGATTCATTTGTACCAATTAAAAAGATAAATAAACAAGATGAATATATAGACAAATTAATTAAATCATACAATTTACAAATAAACACTATAAAAAGCCGTGTTTATCCATTGAACGAAGCAACAGTACACCTTTTAGGTTATGTGGGTCCAATTAATTCTGACGAGTTAAAAAGTAAGCAATTTAGAAACTATAGCAAAAATACTGTTATTGGAAAAAAAGGCTTAGAACGCCTCTATGATAAACAATTGCAAAACACTGATGGTTTTAAGGTATCCATTGCAAATACTTATGACAATAAACCTTTAGACACATTATTGGAGAAAAAGGCTGAAAACGGAAAAGATCTTCATTTAACTATAGATGCTAGAGTACAAGAAAGTATTTATAAACATATGAAAAATGACGATGGATCTGGTACAGCATTACAACCAAAAACTGGAGAAATTTTAGCTTTGGTAAGTACCCCATCGTACGATGTTTATCCATTCATGAATGGATTAAGCAATAATGACTACCGTAAATTAACTAACAATAAAAAAGAGCCTTTGCTCAACAAATTTCAAATCACTACATCACCAGGTTCAACCCAAAAAATATTAACATCTATTATAGCCTTAAAAGAAAATAAACTAGACAAAAATACTAATTTTGATATTTATGGTAAGGGTTGGCAAAAAGATGCATCATGGGGTAATTATAATATCACAAGATTTAAAGTAGTAGACGGCAATATCGATTTAAAGCAAGCAATAGAATCATCAGACAACATATTTTTTGCCCGCATTGCATTAGCATTAGGAGCCAAAAAATTTGAGCAAGGTATGCAAGATTTGGGAATCGGTGAAAATATCCCGAGTGATTATCCCTTTTATAAAGCACAAATCTCAAATAGTAATTTAAAAAATGAAATATTATTAGCAGATTCAGGATATGGCCAAGGCGAGATACTAGTAAACCCTATACAAATTTTATCAATATACAGTGCTTTAGAAAATAACGGAAATATACAAAATCCTCATGTTTTACGTAAAACAAAATCTCAAATATGGAAAAAAGATATTATACCTAAAAAAGACATAGATATATTAACTAATGGTATGGAACGTGTAGTTAATAAAACACATAGGGATGATATATACAAAAATTATGCCCGAATTATTGGTAAATCTGGCACAGCAGAATTAAAAATGAATCAAGGGGAAACTGGAAGACAAATAGGTTGGTTTGTTTCATATAATAAAAATAATCCTAATATGTTAATGGCGATTAATGTTAAAGACGTTCAAAATAAAGGGATGGCCAGCTATAATGCTACTATATCTGGAAAAGTTTATGATGATTTGTATGATAATGGAAAAACTCAATTTGATATAGATCAGTAATTCGAATACTTCTTTTGACTTGGTATTAATTAAAAATAATAGTGAGAAGCGTTTCCACAAAGATTACATTTGTAATATATAGGAGGAATAAAATTGAAAA
```

But this one (and others) do not work:

```
ATGAAAAAGATAAAAATTGTTCCACTTATTTTAATAGTTGTAGTTGTCGGGTTTGGTATATATTTTTATGCTTCCAAAGATAAAGAAATTAATAATACTATTGATGCAATTGAAGATAAAAATTTCAAACAAGTTTATAAAGATAGCAGTTATATTTCTAAAAGCGATAATGGTGAAGTAGAAATGACTGAACGTCCGATAAAAATATATAATAGTTTAGGCGTTAAAGATATAAACATTCAGGATCGTAAAATAAAAAAAGTATCTAAAAATAAAAAACGAGTAGATGCTCAATATAAAATTAAAACAAACTACGGTAACATTGATCGCAACGTTCAATTTAATTTTGTTAAAGAAGATGGTATGTGGAAGTTAGATTGGGATCATAGCGTCATTATTCCAGGAATGCAGAAAGACCAAAGCATACATATTGAAAATTTAAAATCAGAACGTGGTAAAATTTTAGACCGAAACAATGTGGAATTGGCCAATACAGGAACAGCATATGAGATAGGCATCGTTCCAAAGAATGTATCTAAAAAAGATTATAAAGCAATCGCTAAAGAACTAAGTATTTCTGAAGACTATATCAAACAACAAATGGATCAAAATTGGGTACAAGATGATACCTTCGTTCCACTTAAAACCGTTAAAAAAATGGATGAATATTTAAGTGATTTCGCAAAAAAATTTCATCTTACAACTAATGAAACAAAAAGTCGTAACTATCCTCTAGGAAAAGCGACTTCACATCTATTAGGTTATGTTGGTCCCATTAACTCTGAAGAATTAAAACAAAAAGAATATAAAGGCTATAAAGATGATGCAGTTATTGGTAAAAAGGGACTCGAAAAACTTTACGATAAAAAGCTCCAACATGAAGATGGCTATCGTGTCACAATCGTTGACGATAATAGCAATACAATCGCACATACATTAATAGAGAAAAAGAAAAAAGATGGCAAAGATATTCAACTAACTATTGATGCTAAAGTTCAAAAGAGTATTTATAACAACATGAAAAATGATTATGGCTCAGGTACTGCTATCCACCCTCAAACAGGTGAATTATTAGCACTTGTAAGCACACCTTCATATGACGTCTATCCATTTATGTATGGCATGAGTAACGAAGAATATAATAAATTAACCGAAGATAAAAAAGAACCTCTGCTCAACAAGTTCCAGATTACAACTTCACCAGGTTCAACTCAAAAAATATTAACAGCAATGATTGGGTTAAATAACAAAACATTAGACGATAAAACAAGTTATAAAATCGATGGTAAAGGTTGGCAAAAAGATAAATCTTGGGGTGGTTACAACGTTACAAGAAATAAAGTGGTAAATGGTAATATCGACTTAAAACAAGCAATAGAATCATCAGATAACATTTTCTTTGCTAGAGTAGCACTCGAATTAGGCAGTAAGAAATTTGAAAAAGGCATGAAAAAACTAGGTGTTGGTGAAGATATACCAAGTGATTATCCATTTTATAATGCTCAAATTTCAAACAAAAATTTAGATAATGAAATATTATTAGCTGATTCAGGTTACGGACAAGGTGAAATACTGATTAACCCAGTACAGATCCTTTCAATCTATAGCGCATTAGAAAATAATGGCAATATTAACGCACCTCACTTATTAAAAGACACGAAAAACAAAGTTTGGAAGAAAAATATTATTTCCAAAGAAAATATCAATCTATTAACTGATGGTATGCAACAAGTCGTAAATAAAACACATAAAGAAGATATTTATAGATCTTATGCAAACTTAATTGGCAAATCCGGTACTGCAGAACTCAAAATGAAACAAGGAGAAACTGGCAGACAAATTGGGTGGTTTATATCATATGATAAAGATAATCCAAACATGATGATGGCTATTAATGTTAAAGATGTACAAGATAAAGGAATGGCTAGCTACAATGCCAAAATCTCAGGTAAAGTGTATGATGAGCTATATGAGAACGGTAATAAAAAATACGATATAGATGAATAA
```

Depending on the query, the byte value in the second line of the error changes. It does seem like there's an issue with the database, but I have downloaded it twice and am getting the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple solution, BLAST version was not current using sudo apt-get. Download latest blast executables from NCBI FTP and the issue should go away if it is the same

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Could you please specify the version for which it worked for you? (i.e., the output of "blastn -version")

Comment: I updated to version 2.12

Answer (score 0):

I met the same problem, have you solve it ?
I checked my sequences, and I can't see any problem.

But when I try this program with same parameters and my early version sequences, the error disappear.

The early version's sequences is fasta format.
And long sequences was divided into several lines. (didn't merge into one single line)

I still don't know why, but this message maybe helpful.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: See my answer above.